# Fréchet L-Spaces

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, real-analysis, ho.history-overview, limits-and-convergence

According to the paper [The emergence of open sets, closed sets, and limit points
in analysis and topology](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.hm.2008.01.001) famous mathematician [Maurice Fréchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Ren%C3%A9_Fr%C3%A9chet) who introduced the concept of metric spaces has also introduced another similar class of abstract spaces  called **Limit spaces** based on the primitive idea of the limit of an infinite sequence in 1904, which was defined as follows:

> An L-space is a set $X$ together with a function $F : S\to X,$ where $S$ is a set of infinite sequences of members of $X$.

If $(x_n)\in S$, then $F(x_n)$ was said to be the *“limit of the sequence $(x_n)$"* satisfying following two axioms:

> $A_1$: If $(x_n)$ is a constant sequence whose value is $a$, then $F(x_n)=a$.
>
> $A_2$: If $F(x_n)=a$, then for any sub-sequence of $(x_n)$ given by $(x_{n_k})$ we have $F(x_{n_k})=a$.

I would like to know more about mathematics on L-spaces. But I could not find any thing by just Googling.
Where could I find about these spaces?

Comment: Two months ago, I ask [the same question on Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661241/fr%c3%a9chet-l-spaces) and no one answered. Later I thought that this would be more suitable to MathOverflow.

Comment: It seems that [Terry Pratchett also studied](http://disc-wiki.confusedherring.com/wiki/L-space) $L$-spaces ;)

Comment: Today, a Frechet L-space means a space with two properties: Frechet (also known as Frechet-Urysohn) and L. Thus, the title should better be "Frechet's L-space". BTW, (nowadays) a space is Frechet-Urysohn if every point in the closure of a set is a limit of a sequence, and a space is L if it is hereditarily Lindelof and nonseparable. These are not entirely unrelated notions.

Comment: As a search strategy I tried `Fréchet "Limit Spaces"`.

Comment: Nowadays, an L-space is a regular hereditarily Lindelöf space that is not separable. I believe it's also a notion in metric topological vector spaces. A somewhat overloaded word.

Comment: You might be interested in Problems 1.7.18-1.7.20 in Engelking's book and references listed there. You can look also at [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/when-is-a-notion-of-convergence-induced-by-a-topology/37643#37643). And of course, it might be reasonable to try to have a look at papers which [cite the original Frechet's paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=1803710952850005944).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that these spaces don't go under the name of $L$ spaces anymore. Actually, I am not sure if there is a consensus on how these structures are called today.

A good place to start is the fairly recent book

- [**Convergence Structures and Applications to Functional
  Analysis**](https://books.google.com/books?id=OdwXRK-i9YgC&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PR4#v=onepage&q&f=false)  by R. Beattie and H.-P. Butzmann, Kluwer, 2002

where these structures are named **convergence spaces**, more precisely **sequential convergence spaces** and are studied in [chapter 1.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=OdwXRK-i9YgC&pg=PA51).

Another, slightly older, reference is the article (in French)

- [**Convergence du type $\mathcal{L}$**](https://eudml.org/doc/210660), Jan Kisyński, Colloquium
  Mathematicae, 1960

but I haven't read that one.